# Fancybox 2.0 not loading on localhost

Tags: fancybox, localhost, loading, dreamweaver, mamp

I'm working on a website using Dreamweaver CS5 and I'm trying to load Fancybox 2.0.4 on dreamweaver cs5 while working on the website on my localhost using Live view to no avail. In addition Fancybox will not load in the same localhost environment using any browser (Safari, Firefox, Chrome, Opera). However, when I load the page to the remote website ti works perfectly. I'm using MAMP as my localhost server on MAC OS X Lion. I have been banging my head for weeks and have not found a solution. Any help will be appreciated. Below a copy of the code I'm using (copied from the fancybox website for testing purposes) that tested my theory that fancybox is not working on localhost while it works on remote server, the website with the same code working is http://www.gabrielelopez.com/Untitled-1.html

Thank you in advance for any help,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1  /DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>


<!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="fancybox/lib/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"> </script>

<!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-    3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" media="screen" />

<!-- Add fancyBox - button helper (this is optional) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox - thumbnail helper (this is optional) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".various").fancybox({
    maxWidth    : 800,
    maxHeight   : 600,
    fitToView   : false,
    width       : '70%',
    height      : '70%',
    autoSize    : false,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    type : 'iframe',
});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>


<a class="various fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/L9szn1QQfas?autoplay=1">Youtube (iframe)</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to access http://localhost/fancybox/lib/jquery-1.7.1.min.js and see if you can get the file.
If not try to change the source of files you want to load. 
Make sure you have read&write permissions for the folder your scripts are in.

or upload the scripts to a webserver and change all paths to the sources like:

src="fancybox/lib/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"

to

src="http://www.yourdomain.com/fancybox/lib/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for your prompt reply, but unfortunately I could not access http://localhost/fancybox/lib/jquery-1.7.1.min.js file Not Found, and the file is there, also checked permissions of the folders and they are all read and write. And changing src="fancybox/lib/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" to src="http://www.gabrielelopez.com/fancybox/lib/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" or http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js did nothing to help my case... do you have other ideas?